# How can I ignore an apostrophe within a quote in php?

Tags: php, variables, escaping, quotes

I have a php variable referring to a string that contains apostrophes, but when I quote this variable, it thinks I am trying to end the string. My variable is reading from an array of table data, so I can not go in and put a "\" before every apostrophe in the table. If `$foo` contains the string "don't", how do I correctly say `'$foo'` without it trying to end the string. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn about _escaping_.

Comment: this seems db-related and that quote is being taken as an sql injection. The question's unclear though due to lack of code. In any case, use a prepared statement.

Comment: If you're not going to update your question to hold the full code for this, then I for one cannot help you. The question could also get closed with a few possible duplicates. For that (being unclear) I gave the question a -1.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that you need to add escape characters ("\") before the apostrophes.

To do this on the fly with the database data you can use the php function addslashes.

so:

```
$escapedString = addslashes($string);
```

You could also do this with the string replace function for higher precision:

```
$escapedString = str_replace("'", "\'", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's addslashes [PHP Manual - Add slashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

```
$foo = addslashes($foo);
```